# SSR afterNextRender problem in Angular 17

Tags: angular, angular-universal

guys. . I encountered a problem when I try to migrate to SSR in Angular 17. My app is client only in Angular 16.
I have a keycloak service which is used to authenticate the user.
I have to use the code below to make it working

```js
    afterNextRender(() => {
      zone.run(() => {
        this.keycloak = new Keycloak('assets/keycloak.json');
        this.promise = this.keycloak.init({onLoad: 'check-sso'});
        this.promise.then(authenticated => {
          this.init = true;
          console.log('authenticated:', authenticated);
          if (authenticated) {
            this.keycloak?.loadUserProfile().then(profile => {
              this.profile = profile;
            })
          }
        });
      });
      setInterval(this.updateToken.bind(this), 60000);
    });
```

I have to make it run in a zone. Or it doesn't update my @if scope content. Is it intended?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!